# Create Procedure to Insert row & Return SYS_GUID() PK in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, guid

My team has two Oracle DB tables - one for capturing service call requests and responses, another for logging certain kinds of errors. Currently the two tables are not related. Both of them use DEFAULT SYS_GUID() to generate their PK's on insert - but one of them stores this as raw(16) and the other as varchar2(50 BYTE).

I'm creating a table that has a FK to each of those tables, and by consensus vote I am required to use a SYS_GUID() as the PK.

Work bans pasting code here so rough sample code follows, assume typos/weird formatting are not present in code/scripts:

```
table SERVICE_CALLS
SERVICE_CALL_ID RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() PRIMARY KEY,
REQUEST_DATETIME DATE NOT NULL,
RESPONSE_DATETIME DATE,
REQUEST_PAYLOAD CLOB,
RESPONSE_PAYLOAD CLOB

table ERROR_LOGS
ERROR_LOG_ID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() PRIMARY KEY,
ERROR_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
ERROR_TEXT CLOB NOT NULL
```

**My new table**:

```
table SERVICE_CALL_ERROR_LOG_RELATION
RELATION_ID RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() PRIMARY KEY,
INSERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
SERVICE_CALL_ID RAW(16) NOT NULL,
ERROR_LOG_ID CARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT FK_SERVICE_CALL
FOREIGN KEY (SERVICE_CALL_ID),
REFERENCES SERVICE_CALLS(SERVICE_CALL_ID),

CONSTRAINT FK_ERROR_LOG
FOREIGN KEY (ERROR_LOG_ID)
REFERENCES ERROR_LOGS (ERROR_LOG_ID);
```

ERROR_LOG will have a many-to-one relationship with SERVICE_CALL, but not every ERROR_LOG will have an associated SERVICE_CALL. The RELATION table will only be populated if an ERROR_LOG is created when a SERVICE_CALL_ID is available; the availability will be determined in the actual application. If there is no SERVICE_CALL_ID, we'll just insert a record into the ERROR_LOGS table without touching the RELATION table.

I don't have much experience with stored procedures, but my goal is to create a stored procedure that will take in a SERVICE_CALL_ID (null or raw(16)) and an ERROR_TEXT (CLOB).

- If SERVICE_CALL_ID is null, then I'll just insert a new record into
  ERROR_LOGS using the ERROR_TEXT and a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
- If SERVICE_CALL_ID is not null, then I want to insert a new record into ERROR_LOGS, **fetch the auto-generated ERROR_LOG_ID**, and insert a new record into SERVICE_CALL_ERROR_LOG_RELATION using SERVICE_CALL_ID and the fetched ERROR_LOG_ID.

Fetching the ERROR_LOG_ID is the part I'm having trouble with. I've found some answers here about getting the newly inserted record's ID if it's a sequence, but those are obviously a bit different since sequences have predictable values... Is there any way to fetch that auto-generated ID on the new record?

Final note: When there's one ERROR_LOG insert, there tend to be multiple within milliseconds, so I can't rely on, say, fetching the most recent record since by the time that processes there could be other records inserted.

Comment: perhaps stupid question, but how service_call_id can't be null if is NOT NULL in all your tables ?

Comment: Not every ERROR_LOG will correspond to a SERVICE_CALL, so if we want to insert an z ERROR_LOG entry without relating it to a SERVICE_CALL entry, we'll pass null for SERVICE_CALL_ID to the procedure. I've updated the originated question to clarify.

Comment: have you think in using a trigger for this rather than a procedure ? taking into account the logic you describe

Comment: I haven't considered using a trigger; I'll take a look now. Thanks!

Comment: keep in mind that the trigger, whatever it does, will delay the commit of the original transaction. You were talking about miliseconds, so keep that in mind

Comment: Hmm, so I could add an after insert trigger for the error table, but then I couldn't fetch the service call id. The problem is that the two inputs I need are equally necessary, totally unrelated, and non sequential. I thought about trying to compare the error timestamp in the trigger; if the error timestamp falls between the request and response timestamps, then I could use that, but multiple service calls can be in flight at the same time so that isn't ideal either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I still have to put it all together in my actual environment, but this little test procedure works for me.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE() RETURNING {COLUMN} INTO {VARIABLE}
```

Example below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOG_SERVICE_ERROR(
SERVICE_CALL_ID IN RAW,
ERROR_TEXT IN CLOB
)
AS
v_ERROR_LOG_ID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);
BEGIN

INSERT INTO ERROR_LOGS(SYS_GUID(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ERROR_TEXT) RETURNING ERROR_LOG_ID INTO v_ERROR_LOG_ID;

IF SERVICE_CALL_ID IS NOT NULL THEN

INSERT INTO SERVICE_CALL_ERROR_LOG_RELATION(SYS_GUID(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, SERVICE_CALL_ID, v_ERROR_LOG_ID);

END IF;

END;
```